# Angular 6 Concat string for BindLabel in <ng-select tag>

Tags: angular, concatenation, angular-ngselect

Using Angular 6, I want to **concat Firstname and Lastname** in **bindLabel** inside **ng-select tag**  ?

*Here is my html :
ng-select [items]="persons" bindLabel="LastName" bindValue="Id"  [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" placeholder="person"*

Any idea ? 
bindLabel="LastName + '   ' +FirstName" **=> doesn't work**
bindLabel="person.Name as (person.LastName + ' ' person.FirstName) for person in persons" **=> doesn't work**

Answer (score 14):

A better way for display the full name is:

```
 <ng-select required [items]="buddies" bindLabel="firstName" #buddiesInput="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userSelect" name="userSelect" >
                        <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
                            {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
                            {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </ng-select>
```

Comment: bindLabel="firstName" should not be necessary anymore I think.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty old question but I will still answer. I happened to catch this question as I am also looking for the same solution.

Not maybe the best practice or there might be much better solution but I just created a map for my array so I could create a new field for `full_name`.

See code below if this could help you out.

**template**:

```
  <ng-select 
    [(ngModel)]="_selected_user" 
    [items]="_all_users" 
    placeholder="Select User"
    bindLabel="full_name"
    bindValue="id"
    >

    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
        <div><span></span><span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{item.full_name }}</span></div>
        <small>User ID: <b>{{item.user_id}}</b> </small>
    </ng-template>

  </ng-select>
```

**component**:

```
      users.map(
        (user: any) => {
          user.full_name = user.last_name + ', ' + member.first_name + ' ' + member.middle_name
          return member;
        }
      )
```

This one will enable searching via `first_name` or `last_name` or `middle_name` or altogether in one search key.

Comment: Answer for this Link:   https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-ng-select-searchfunc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts